# Why can I not use lambda expression directly in implicit operator?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

The following code does not compile in .Net as it throws an error about lambda expressions cannot be converted to delegate of Action directly.

```
public class Sample {
    public static implicit operator Sample(Action action) { return new Sample(); }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Sample y = void () => { };
}
```

This can be fixed by casting the expression into Action delegate, as follow

```
Sample y = (Action)(void () => { });
```

Or it can be fixed by creating an intermediate variable, as follow

```
var x = void () => { };
Sample y = x;
```

Question is why does not the compiler recognizes this by default? Why is there has to be an intermediate variable?

How does the signature of the operator needs to be changed to allow lambda expression to be accepted. I do not want to use `LambdaExpression` or `Delegate` as the implicit operator.

I would expect the following code to compile `Sample y = void () => { };`, since introducing the intermediate variable fixed the issue.